# How to set the distance between the top of the page and the table of contents, list of figures and tables to 2.5cm

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

I tried using the following codes to set the distance between the top of the page and the table of contents, list of figures and tables to 2.5cm, but it fails to work. I need help with an adjustment that will not affect the usual spacing for chapters other than these. This is the code that I have used that failed to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\vspace{-2.5cm} \tableofcontents}
{\vspace{-2.5cm} \listofigures}
{\vspace{-2.5cm} \listoftables}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the left, right, and bottom margins? Should they be 2.5cm as well?

Comment: The left is 3.7cm, bottom 2.5cm, but the top is what I am having problems with. Using the MWE you just gave, the contents head did not shift upwards to ensure 2.5cm between the tip of the paper and the "Contents" title.

Answer (score 1):

(I rewrote this answer significantly after receiving a comment from the OP, which indicated that -- contrary to the impression created by the OP's code fragments -- interest lies in the `report` document class, *not* the `article` document class.)

I gather that the top page margin -- and maybe some of the other page margins as well -- is equal to 2.5cm. I further gather that the headers of the table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables -- but *not* the headers of "regular" chapter-level entries -- are supposed to be typeset at very top of the text block, i.e., without any whitespace.

If these impressions are correct, I suggest you add the following instructions to the preamble of your document.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

If you're guessing that the `\patchcmd` instruction removes `\vspace*{50\p@}` -- "insert 50pt (about 17.5mm) of vertical whitespace" -- from the definition of the `\@makeschapterhead` macro, you would be correct. (The `\@makeschapterhead` macro is defined by the `report` document class.)

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=2.5cm, hmargin=3.7cm,
            nomarginpar,nohead,showframe % remove these options in your real doc.
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% front matter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

% main matter
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} % <-- switch to arabic numerals

\chapter{Hello World}

\lipsum[1] % one paragraph of filler text

\begin{figure}[h]\caption{Good Morning}\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]\caption{Good Evening}\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just copied your MWE and implemented it. However, it does not work for the report document class. Immediately I change the class to report, the "Contents" heading drops down far below as usual. Kindly help out.

Comment: @AbdulhafeezAyindeAbdulsalam - Please see the revised answer I posted.